# How to convert dates to datetime with numpy and .astype()?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I am trying to convert a date which is stored as a string right now, into a datetime datatype.

With pandas, I can do

```
df[date] = pd.to_datetime(df[date], format='%d%b%Y')
```

I want to be able to do this same process with numpy and store this in a dictionary. Unfortunately, I am missing where to add a `format` parameter. In the [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/arrays.datetime.html), I don't see any information for the way the month is stored in my df.

My approach

```
df= df.astype({'Signature':np.str,'AMT':np.float32,'Role':np.str,'date':np.datetime64})
```

df

```
ID  Signature  AMT   Code   Role          date
1   432        10    dr4    Professional  04Jan2015
1   432        20    grf    Professional  05Jan2015
1   432        50    htg    Professional  21Jan2015
```

Comment: 'The parser in NumPy 1.7 is quite strict about only accepting ISO 8601 dates, with a few convenience extensions.' Pandas has more flexibility allowing you to specify a format outside of ISO 8601 dates.

Comment: As a workaround you could use `strftime` and `strptime` from the `time` module: `np.datetime64(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.strptime('05Jan2015', '%d%b%Y')))` Not pretty, not vectorized, but does the job.